# android application can't auto generate R.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my android application, there are no errors in my source codes or my xml filess.

my adt is adt22. 
my operating system is ubuntu 12.04.
my jdk is java version "1.6.0_27"

This is my second ask question. I wanted to post some screenshots about my problem  but I have no reputation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

R.java is not regenerated when you have an error in your XML file,if there is no error then try cleaning your project....Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`R` is a file that is autogenerated by `ADT` whenever your project is built.

Ocasionally, you will encounter a situation where you do not seem to have any errors in any of your files, `.java`, or `.xml`, and `R` will still not generate.

In most cases, you can force the project to clean and rebuild itself by cleaning it. To do this, go

> Project -> Clean... -> Ok

Before cleaning you should clear your console, and check for any output provided.

Answer (score 0):

R.java is created by default when you are build the application. if not generating, then clean your project or please check your resource file like xml file are have any errors or check your image or xml resource file contains any capital letter in it name. in your **image or .xml res(drawable) file Names should not start with capital letter or should not contain capital letter**.